# jQuery Previous DIV Class

Tags: jquery

I' am using jQuery to get the previous DIV with Class "our-partner-readmore". I have tried alot but was not possible in doing it.

HTML

```
<div class="our-partner-readmore"><a class="accordion-toggle btn-readmore collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2"></a></div>    

<div class="our-partner-readmore"><a class="accordion-toggle btn-readmore collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" href="#collapse2"></a></div>
```

JS

```
$('a.btn-readmore').on("click", function(){
    var is_collapsed = $(this).hasClass("collapsed");
    alert(is_collapsed);
        if(is_collapsed){
            $(this).prev('.our-partner-readmore').addClass("none");
            $(this).next('.our-partner-readmore-closed').removeClass("none");
        } else {
            $(this).prev('.our-partner-readmore-closed').addClass("none");
            $(this).next('.our-partner-readmore').removeClass("none");
    }
});
```

More Explaination

Whenever some clicks on the "a.btn-readmore", Using jQuery am trying to get the previous div class "our-partner-readmore" dynamically.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue might be solved using jquery parent function. Here is the api [detail](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).

```
$(this).parent(); //Will give you the parent
```

Comment: What if I want to get the class of next div jquery

Comment: Do you want to check if the parent has a particular class ? If so use the .hasClass('our-partner-readmor') method if not look at the .attr('class')

Answer (score 1):

```
         $(this).prev and   $(this).next are to search for the siblings
```

Since the div on which you want to apply the class is the parents of clicked link so frist to go to its parents

so you can write the code like

```
        $('a.btn-readmore').on("click", function(){
            var is_collapsed = $(this).hasClass("collapsed");
            alert(is_collapsed);
                if(is_collapsed){
                    $(this).parents('.our-partner-readmore').prev().addClass("none");
                    $(this).parents('.our-partner-readmore-closed').next().removeClass("none");
                } else {
                    $(this).parents('.our-partner-readmore-closed').addClass("none");
                    $(this).parents('.our-partner-readmore').removeClass("none");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) gives you the previous sibling of the elements, what you need is an ancestor element

Also you can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the nearest ancestor matching the given selector

```
$(this).closest('.our-partner-readmore').addClass("none");
```